# Let script modify transform position even if the gameobject is disabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Main Camera position to make an appear and disappear. For example, if the `camera.main.transform.position = (0,2,0);` make the object appear otherwise make it disappear.

The object in this case a basic `Cube`. I started using `setActive` function but as it turns out once you have `setActive` as `false, Update` function on the specific object does not run. I have added the script I was using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class backandforth : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 2.5f;
    GameObject targetObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        targetObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        targetObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //move the cube from (0,0,0)
        if (Camera.main.transform.position== new Vector3(0, 2, 0)) { 
            transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 5), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 5);
        }
        else
        {
            targetObject.SetActive(true);
            transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 5), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 100);
            //gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the hierarchy view of the setup to make the GameObject definition clear. 
[image]

Any suggestion on how do I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: put cube in an empty parent gameobject and move the script to be attached tothe parent object. that way you can disable the child cube while the script runs on the parent and the script can set the position of the parent gameobject.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the update method should be like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Camera.main.transform.position== new Vector3(0, 2, 0)) {
        //if the camera.main.transform.position = (0,2,0); make the object appear
        targetObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise make it disappear
        targetObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```